# Why I get NAN when calculate corr of those two series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas Series object:

```
print(s1)
print("="*80)
print(s2)

# output

0   -0.443538
1   -0.255012
2   -0.582948
3   -0.393485
4    0.430831
5    0.232216
6   -0.014269
7   -0.133158
8    0.127162
9   -1.855860
Name: s1, dtype: float64
================================================================================
29160   -0.650857
29161   -0.135428
29162    0.039544
29163    0.241506
29164   -0.793352
29165   -0.054500
29166    0.901152
29167   -0.660474
29168    0.098551
29169    0.822022
Name: s2, dtype: float64
```

And I want to calculate corr of those two series:

```
s1.corr(s2)

#output

nan
```

I don't know why I get 'nan' here, using numpy gives the correct result:

```
np.corrcoef(s1,s2)[0][1]

#output

-0.4918385039519204
```

Did I do something wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your series indices are not aligned. Pandas realigns `s2` on `s1` yielding only NaNs.

You can force the index of `s1` on `s2` using [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html):

```
s1.corr(s2.set_axis(s1.index))
```

Output: `-0.49183852303556697`

Comment: Thanks, I don't know pandas will do "data alignment" when calculate corr. But I checked the the doc and found that `Series.set_axis()` may do underlying  data copy, so I think I should still use numpy to calculate corr.

Comment: Yes, using numpy is probably the best in this case